# Integrate $\sin^3(x) / (2-\sin^2(x)) dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

I want to integrate the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^3(x)}{2-\sin^2(x)}$.

One possibility to do this is to use the "Weierstraß-Substitution" and transform the result into partial fractions after substituting. But this is very much to calculate.

There should be another way to integrate $f$, that should look like this: 
Substitute t=cos(x), then add the differentiative of $\cos(x)$ which is equal to $-\sin(x)$, transform it a little by using the trigonometric pythagoras and substitute again.

This was what another person told me, but I realised now that I do not really understand what he meant. Does anybode else (or does anybody else see a quite similar way to integrate f?)?

The Problem is that when we substitute $t=\cos x$, we have to add the derivative of $x = \arccos t$, which is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$, what does not look by far like any kind of sinus.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Set $\cos x=u\implies-\sin x\ dx=du$

$$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{2-\sin^2x}dx=\int\frac{\sin^2x}{2-\sin^2x}\sin x\ dx$$

$$=\int\frac{1-u^2}{2-(1-u^2)}(-du)$$

$$=-\int\frac{2-(1+u^2)}{1+u^2}du$$

Hope the rest should not be too tough